# Salesforce for Outlook mail upload

Tags: community, email, upload, salesforce-for-outlook

When I try to upload an email to Salesforce it is automatically added to a contact profile of a colleague in my company. Would you please advise how to fix this in order to see the emails in my unresolved items and link them to the correlated Account record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a default feature of 'Salesforce for Outlook'. You can control and customise this behaviour based on your preferences to disable it altogether or define rules - read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_sync_contacts_o.htm&language=en_US).

[image]

Additionally, you can also define [handling](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_unresolved_items.htm) for items which are not resolved by Salesforce by default.

[image]